# Request Dispatcher deletes all word from form but first

Tags: java, forms, servlets, request

this is my JSP:

```
<div>
  <b>${reply}</b>
</div>
<form action="runCommand" method="post" name="myform">
  File:<input name="commandfile" type="text" size="10" value=${commandfile}> </input><br />
  Command:<input name="commandinput" type="text" size="10" value=${commandinput}> </input><br />
  No delete File: <input type="checkbox" name="no_del_file" value=${no_del_file} ><br>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

And this is my java servlet code:

```
 public class RunCommand extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5711290708294275382L;
String commands = null;
File dir = null;
BufferedReader is = null;
BufferedReader es = null;
boolean retval = false;
int testwin = 0;
int fileok = 0;
String completefilename = null;
File filecheck = null;
private BufferedReader outfile;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.setAttribute("commandfile", "commandfile");
    request.setAttribute("commandinput", "commandinput");
    request.setAttribute("no_del_file", "no_del_file");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    ServletContext application = getServletContext();
    performTask(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    performTask(request, response);
}

    private int getWin() {
    Process Checkprocess;
    try {
        String Checkcommand = "cmd /c tasklist /V /FI \"WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:*\"";
        Checkprocess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Checkcommand);
        String Checkline;
        String Checkval = "Administrator:";

        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Checkprocess.getInputStream()));
        while ((Checkline = is.readLine()) != null) {
            retval = Checkline.contains(Checkval);
            if (retval = true) {
                testwin = 1;
                break;
            } else
                testwin = 0;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return testwin;
    }

    private int getFile() {

    filecheck = new File(completefilename);

    while (fileok == 0) {
        if (filecheck.exists()) {
            fileok = 1;
            break;
        }

    }
    return fileok;

     }

    private void performTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        String commandbuild = request.getParameter("commandinput");
        String commandfilename = request.getParameter("commandfile");
        String[] no_del_file = request.getParameterValues("no_del_file");

        final SimpleDateFormat datefor = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String timeadd = datefor.format(timestamp);

        completefilename = "C:\\tmp\\" + commandfilename + "_" + timeadd + ".txt ";

        String commandfull = "db2 -tvz " + completefilename + commandbuild;

        commands = "cmd /c db2cwadmin.bat " + commandfull;

        Process process;
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
        String line;
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        data.append("Befehl: " + commands);
        data.append("\n\n\n");

        while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {

            data.append(line);
            data.append("\n");

        }
        es = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = es.readLine()) != null)
            System.err.println(line);

        int exitCode = -100;
        exitCode = process.waitFor();
        if (exitCode == 0) {
            System.out.println("It worked");

            while (testwin != 1) {
                getWin();
                if (testwin == 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            while (fileok != 1) {
                getFile();
                if (fileok == 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            Process EndProcess;
            String Endcommands = "taskkill /F /FI \"WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:*\"";
            EndProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Endcommands);
            int exitCodeEnd = -100;
            exitCodeEnd = EndProcess.waitFor();

            while (exitCodeEnd != 0) {
                EndProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Endcommands);
                exitCodeEnd = EndProcess.waitFor();
                if (exitCodeEnd == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);

            data.append("Fenster wurde geschlossen!");
            data.append("\n");
            data.append("\n");

            File filecheck = new File(completefilename);
            if (filecheck.exists())
                outfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(completefilename));
            String outfilelines;

            while ((outfilelines = outfile.readLine()) != null) {
                data.append(outfilelines);
                data.append("\n");

            }

            request.setAttribute("data", data);
            out.append(data);


            outfile.close();


            if (no_del_file == null) {
            filecheck.delete();
            }

            request.setAttribute("commandfile", commandfilename);
            System.out.println(commandbuild);
            request.setAttribute("commandinput", commandbuild);
            request.setAttribute("no_del_file", no_del_file);
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            ServletContext application = getServletContext();
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/runCommand.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);

        } else
            System.out.println("Something bad happend. Exit code: " + exitCode);

    } // try
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something when wrong: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    } // catch

    finally {

        if (is != null)
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        if (es != null)
            try {
                es.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

    } // finally

    retval = false;
    testwin = 0;
    fileok = 0;
    completefilename = null;

}
```

}

The problem is that only the first word is set. So if the command (I fill out the Command input with this) is:

```
 list applications
```

I only get

```
 list
```

back to command field and the checkbox is not set either when it was set before submiting.

So in the command input field the forward cuts away all words after the first blank and the checkbox is not set again (the check is not preserved). I need the form to be filled out the way it was before submit.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: don't understand the nature of your problem, can you elaborate some more?

Comment: the form should say "list applications" when the request is sent and thanm gets back from the forward part but all I see in the form is "list" so it cuts all word after the first blank.

Comment: what do you mean the form should say "list applications" ? Where is the phrase "list applications" being set?

Comment: In the "Command" input field I write "list application" and when I hit submit I get list in that field instead of leaving it the way it was. (commadn as in the input in the jsp input field at the top source snipplet)

Comment: do you have any javascript that may be altering the text you enter in that field? Have you checked via page inspect/network what your form is actually submitting to see if it is a front end problem or a backend problem?

Comment: No there is not javascript. the jsp is all above and directly before the forward the system.out.println of the commandline is correct. So the problem is in the forward

Comment: can you include more of the servlet code ?

Comment: added full source (without the includes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, from what i understand... when you enter the text "list applications" in your form field it gets submitted to your servlet, but it only returns "list".

Looking at your servlet code, the problem isn't in your backend. So it has to do with something in the frontend which is altering the input.

Let's check this by looking to see what your form is actually sending to your servlet. You can do this by viewing the network tab in chrome developer tools / or firefox developer tools.

The process for chrome developer tools is this:

Right click on your page and click Inspect.

1. Go to the Network tab.
2. Check the box that says "Preserve log". (at the top)
3. Now submit your form while keeping this window open.
4. Look for your servlet url in those requests ("RunCommand"), when you click on it another window will open, here you will see Headers, Preview, Response, Cookies, Timing.
5. Make sure you are viewing the Headers tab, then scroll all the way down to "Form Data". Here you will be able to see what your form is submitting to your servlet, it's a very useful debugging tool. Please let me know what you see there.

Also another thing worth trying is removing `size="10"` from your input field. This limits the text field width and could have something to do with your problem.

Comment: ok so Webtools from FF tell me on return it says value="list" applications="" so for what ever reason the string list applications is transformed to list in the value field and then a new field called applications is created.

Comment: Okay so something on your jsp page is changing the value. Can you please post all your jsp?

Comment: ok I got it solved.... it takes "'"+commandbuild+"'" as return to work. In the backend I need to change request.setAttribute("commandinput", "commandinput"); --> request.setAttribute("commandinput", "'"+commandbuild+"'");